# How can I serialize a array of array in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I work with a web service that allows me to receive objects from my database. Now I try to send an object to my database through my web service. This object when I receive it is presented as an array of tables, now how to serialize it and send it and to the server with Json?

The json of the object that I receive and that I try to send to the server in turn

```
[[" IF THE CROWN FITS - PINCEAUX MAQUILLAGE",20000,20000," IF THE CROWN FITS - PINCEAUX MAQUILLAGE",null,"2"]
```

Comment: What do you want help for? You example are already JSON so it should work? Or do you want to parse the JSON into an object? But since we don't know what each field are, it is really not possible to help you with that. And without an example of your data class, we can't help you with how to convert your data into JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

then as an example:

```
var scores = [
  {'score': 40},
  {'score': 80},
  {'score': 100, 'overtime': true, 'special_guest': null}
];

var jsonText = jsonEncode(scores);
assert(jsonText ==
    '[{"score":40},{"score":80},'
        '{"score":100,"overtime":true,'
        '"special_guest":null}]');
```

quote from the document:

> Only objects of type int, double, String, bool, null, List, or Map (with string keys) are directly encodable into JSON. List and Map objects are encoded recursively.

And check this link https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#dartconvert---decoding-and-encoding-json-utf-8-and-more for more details.